# Laravel - don't parse PHP code in a template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to dump a .php file created from a blade template into the public folder, this way:

```
$html = view('input_file', [
  'variable' => 'text'
]);

File::put(public_path('output_file.php'), $html);
```

where my `input_file.blade.php` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div>{{ $variable }}</div>
  <div><?php echo mt_rand(); ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to achieve is to have `output_file.php` like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div>text</div>
  <div><?php echo mt_rand(); ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So with all blade variables parsed, but PHP tags in place. The problem is that I'm getting this instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div>text</div>
  <div>4324234324324</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to disable php parsing?

Comment: Try using quotes around php code.

Answer (score 0):

Hi 
 You have two ways

#### First Way

Replace all occurences of `<` with `&lt;` (and optionally `>` with `&gt;`) 
Like this:

```php
<pre>
&lt;?php echo 'hello world'; ?&gt;
</pre>
```

#### Second Way

Using `htmlspecialchars` or `highlight_string` like this:

```php
<?php

$code = '<?php
echo "Hello, World!";
?>';

highlight_string($code);

?>
```

And

```php
<?php

$code = '<?php
echo "Hello, World!";
?>';

echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($code) . '</pre>';

?>
```